# Looping over a list in a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Im trying to make a simple blog website with the Flask framework. Each entry in my blog has a title, text and comments. the title and text are stored in a table named entries and the comments in a table named comments that links the comments to the corresponding entry with a foreign key.

The problem I have now is that I want to display the comments in my html file. To do is I want to call a python function named show_comments in my html file while I'm in a for loop. The python function looks like this:

```
@app.route('/comments/<entryid>')
def show_comments(entryid):
    db = get_db()
    curId = db.execute('select id, comment from comments where entry_id=entryid order by     id desc')
    comments = [dict(id=row[0], comment=row[1]) for row in curId.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', comments=comments)
```

My template looks like this:

```
% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
    <dt>Title:
    <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
    <dt>Text:
    <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>  
    <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
  </dl>
</form>
  {% endif %}
  <ul class=entries>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text }}
{{ url_for('show_comments', entryid=entry.id) }}
<ul class=comments>
{% for acomment in comments %}
<li>{{ acomment.comment }}
</li>
</br>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% if session.logged_in %}
<form action="{{ url_for('add_comment', key=entry.id) }}" method=post class=add-entry>
<dl>
    <dt>Comment:
    <dd><textarea name=comment rows=2 cols=40></textarea>
    <dd><input type=submit value=Comment>
  </dl>
</form>
{% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: First of all that's not HTML.  That's an HTML template. Specifically a Jinja2 template it looks like.  And you're not calling any Python functions in the template, you're just looping over a list of comments.  You haven't told us exactly what problem you're having with this, though I can tell you there are a lot of mistakes in your template.

Comment: I should add--you seem to have a misunderstanding of how Flask (and web frameworks in general) work.  Your show_comments function is not called by the template.  It's called by the web framework to generate the response to HTTP requests for your /comments/<entry_id> URLs.  The function then shoves the results of some database query into a list that's used when rendering the template.  In a sense show_comments "calls" (actually renders) the HTML template, not the other way around.

Comment: You have shown us what you have tried, which is commendable. But what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really told us what your problem is so I don't know if this will help.  But I'll point out three specific mistakes here:

The first is that you're putting your comments in an unordered list (the `<ul>` tag) but you put the end tag (`</ul>`) inside the loop instead of outside it.

`</br>` should be written `<br />`, but really that tag doesn't belong there in the first place.

Second, your HTML is broken.  HTML attributes (the parts in tags like `type=submit`) should have quotation marks around the values.  For example, it should look like `type="submit"`.  Most browsers are forgiving when it comes to things like that, but it's better not to count on that and write correct HTML.