# For Loop from database using Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, for-loop, sqlalchemy, jinja2

**Goal:** `{% for loop %}` over a list (using `Jinja2`) and then print out results `{{print}}` in a `HTML` table using Bootstrap. 
**Problem:** List is not printing in the template.

In the `view_config`, I used `query` `.all()` to return a list of all the `assessment_results` objects. They are returning... I confirmed this via terminal/print debugging. However, the `for loop` is not returning the values needed to populate a table; as [read in Jinja2 tutorial](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#loop-filtering). I don't think I need to use a `for loop` in the `view_config` as I have seen others do ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350091/looping-over-a-list-in-a-jinja2-template)), but I am new to this and am trying to figure out how these two programs (`SQLALCHEMY` and `Jinja2`) interact.

An example from the printout after using `.all()` mentioned above:

```
[<Assessment_Result(owner='<User(username ='baseball', firstname ='Jen', lastname ='See', email='girl@aol.com')>', assessment='<Assessment(name='Becoming a Leader', text='better decisions')>')>]
```

view_config code:
**`views.py`**

```
@view_config(route_name='assessment_results', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessment_results.jinja2')
def all_assessment_results(request):
    with transaction.manager: # < --- THIS WAS THE ISSUE ! 
        assessment_results = api.retrieve_assessment_results()
        if not assessment_results:
            raise HTTPNotFound()
        return {'assessment_results': assessment_results}
```

Corresponding Jinja2 template using Bootstrap:
**`assessment_results.jinja2`**

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> Assessment ID </td>
                <td> Assessment </td>
                <td> Owner </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for x in assessment_results %}
                <td>{{ x.assessments|e }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.owners|e}}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td><em>no users found</em></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the documentation

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for

You want to iterate over a `dict`, so consider using `iteritems`, `itervalues` or what ever you want.

Also note that your query will not return a `dict`, it will return a `list` or rows that matched.

I am also not sure if the `for-else` works in jinja. But you should avoid using that anyways.

Comment: Yes, I have a list being returned. I tried the `{% for key,value in assessment_results.iteritems %}` and that did not seem to work either. I got rid of the `for-else`

Comment: what would you suggest using since it is a `list` and I am trying to `loop` over all the results and have them print onto the template. `for-else` does work in jinja, but I am not using it.

Comment: Are you sure `assessment_results` has all the objects in a list? If you want to see that the values are passed there you can use the [pprint filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#pprint) in Jinja. Please note that `list` does not have `iteritems`, you should just use `for value in values`

Comment: updated. also, `for value in values` was the initial attempt. I suppose I thought it would be a list since the code being returned in `view.py` is returning a `list` ... perhaps that is where the issue is? the `return` value `'assessment_results': assessment_results`

Comment: From your traceback, the issue seems to be with the way you are handling your sessions. `x.owners` is making another query and in the template no session is available. What you could do is to use `joined_load` or `subquery_load`, in your query, which would be optimal for the speed of the page load.

Comment: I added the `retrieve_` method just now. May be easier to change the `views.py` config (shown above). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try changing your query to `Assessment_Result.query.all()`. Better yet, `Assessment_Result.query.options(subqueryload(Assessment_Result.owners)).all()`. This problem doesn't have anything to do with the view cofigs.

Comment: I was able to use `for value in values` type of iterator. The issue was the `with transaction.manager()` it kept killing the session for some reason. I don't understand why, but removing that and using the iterator in the template worked. So thank you for your help and patience.